# Saving R loop output into e.g. csv file

Tags: r, loops

I am aware that this probably trivial but I can not solve it. And I have edited the original question a bit as I realized it was not very logical. See the code below:

```
u1 <- rnorm(30)
usq <- 0
for(i in 1:5) 
{
usq[i] <- u1[i]*u1[i]
print(usq[i])
}
```

The output is (your might be different in terms of numbers):

```
[1] 0.3501974
[1] 0.01937814
[1] 0.4053783
[1] 0.0005323552
[1] 1.459631
```

All I want to do is to save this output as e.g. CSV file with one or two columns. I happy to be pointed out to any spot where this question was answered. I could not for the life of me find it... I have tried:

```
write.csv(matrix(1:5, ncol=1), "Results.csv")
```

Comment: To make a CSV file with two columns, use `write.csv` on a data frame or matrix with two columns. Like `write.csv(matrix(index, ncol = 2), "my.csv")`. If you want something else, please be more specific. If you want to append to a CSV in a loop, you can use `writeLines` or `sink` or something like that, but it will be much easier and faster to store your result in an R object and then write it all at once at the end.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I have edited the question...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the numbers are stand-ins for something a lot more complex -  for loops in R are generally avoided - and it's rare that there isn't a better options somewhere.

To answer your question though, you need (as Gregor pointed out) `write.csv`.  The one addition I would make is that the first time you call it, you need to make a new file.

```
write.csv(output_as_dataframe_or_matrix, file = "path_to_file.csv")
```

after that, you need to tell it not to overwrite what you had before:

```
write.csv(output_as_dataframe_or_matrix, file = "path_to_file.csv", append = TRUE)
```

Here's how you can achieve this (note that I'm removing the for loops.  R will perform many operations on each element of a vector, and its much more efficient when you have it work this way.

```
u1 <- rnorm(30
usq <- u1^2 # or u1 * u1
print(usq)

write.csv(usq, "Results.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you Melissa, but the loop was an essential part of my question as the problem of course was much more complex than getting rnorm values. I have managed to answer this question myself - see below.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably not the most eloquently written question (my apologies for that) but the answer to it should be that the "empty container" has to be created first and then filled with numbers from the loop calculations. To solve my issue from above the following code did the job:

```
output<-matrix(0,5,1)
output<-as.data.frame(output)
u1 <- rnorm(30)
usq <- 0
for(i in 1:5) 
{
usq[i] <- u1[i]*u1[i]
print(usq[i])
output$V1[i]<-usq[i]
}
write.csv(output, "Results.csv")
```